# Extracting data in Python script from Paraview 4.2

Tags: python, numpy, vtk, paraview

I'm trying to extract data from a slice in a Python script using Paraview 4.2. I have something like this:

```
from paraview.numpy_support import vtk_to_numpy
from paraview.simple import *
import os

os.environ["DISPLAY"] = ":0"
paraview.simple._DisableFirstRenderCameraReset()

# create a new 'XDMF Reader'
xDMFtemporalFieldsxmf = XDMFReader(FileNames=['<pathtodata>/XDMF.temporalFields.xmf'])

# Properties modified on xDMFtemporalFieldsxmf
xDMFtemporalFieldsxmf.PointArrayStatus = ['DensityProperty-mesh', 'VelocityField']
xDMFtemporalFieldsxmf.CellArrayStatus = []

# create a new 'Slice'
slice1 = Slice(Input=xDMFtemporalFieldsxmf)

# create a new 'Clip'
clip1 = Clip(Input=slice1)
clip1.ClipType = 'Scalar'
clip1.Value = 1200.0
```

So all I want to do is extract the VelocityField data from the clip, preferably with coordinate locations for each data point.

Here is some of my exploration:

```
>> print clip1
<paraview.servermanager.Clip object at 0x7f1a14e356d0>

>> print clip1.PointData.keys()
[]

>> print clip1.FieldData.keys()
[]

>> proxy = servermanager.Proxy(proxy=clip1.SMProxy)
>> for property in proxy:
>>     print property
<paraview.servermanager.Scalar object at 0x7f1a4e346850>
<paraview.servermanager.Slice object at 0x7f1a14e35190>
None
0
0
[None, '']
0
1200.0

>> print paraview.numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(clip1.SMProxy)
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d5fe9e4e150c> in <module>()
----> 1 print paraview.numpy_support.vtk_to_numpy(clip1.SMProxy)

/home/luke/Programs/paraview4.2/lib/site-packages/paraview/numpy_support.pyc in vtk_to_numpy(vtk_array)
    202 
    203     """
--> 204     typ = vtk_array.GetDataType()
    205     assert typ in get_vtk_to_numpy_typemap().keys(), \
    206            "Unsupported array type %s"%typ

AttributeError: GetDataType

>> data = servermanager.Fetch(clip1)
>> print data
vtkUnstructuredGrid (0x6276dc0)
  Debug: Off
  Modified Time: 37918079
  Reference Count: 1
  Registered Events: (none)
  Information: 0x65f2f40
  Data Released: False
  Global Release Data: Off
  UpdateTime: 0
  Field Data:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 37918063
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Number Of Arrays: 0
    Number Of Components: 0
    Number Of Tuples: 0
  Number Of Points: 0
  Number Of Cells: 0
  Cell Data:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 37918077
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Number Of Arrays: 0
    Number Of Components: 0
    Number Of Tuples: 0
    Copy Tuple Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 )
    Interpolate Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 )
    Pass Through Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 )
    Scalars: (none)
    Vectors: (none)
    Normals: (none)
    TCoords: (none)
    Tensors: (none)
    GlobalIds: (none)
    PedigreeIds: (none)
    EdgeFlag: (none)
  Point Data:
    Debug: Off
    Modified Time: 37918079
    Reference Count: 1
    Registered Events: (none)
    Number Of Arrays: 0
    Number Of Components: 0
    Number Of Tuples: 0
    Copy Tuple Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 )
    Interpolate Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 )
    Pass Through Flags: ( 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 )
    Scalars: (none)
    Vectors: (none)
    Normals: (none)
    TCoords: (none)
    Tensors: (none)
    GlobalIds: (none)
    PedigreeIds: (none)
    EdgeFlag: (none)
  Bounds: 
    Xmin,Xmax: (1, -1)
    Ymin,Ymax: (1, -1)
    Zmin,Zmax: (1, -1)
  Compute Time: 0
  Number Of Points: 0
  Point Coordinates: 0
  Locator: 0
  Number Of Pieces: 1
  Piece: -1
  Ghost Level: 0
```

Any further exploration always seems to lead me back to FieldDataInformation or PointDataInformation objects - and not the actual data!

A previous method that worked for extracting point XYZ positions was this:

```
data = servermanager.Fetch(clip1)
d2 = data.GetPoints()
xyz = zeros((d2.GetNumberOfPoints(), 3))
for i in range(d2.GetNumberOfPoints()):
    xyz[i,:] = data.GetPoint(i)
```

EDIT - the output for this is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-e34f36729df1> in <module>()
      1 data = servermanager.Fetch(clip1)
      2 d2 = data.GetPoints()
----> 3 xyz = zeros((d2.GetNumberOfPoints(), 3))
      4 for i in range(d2.GetNumberOfPoints()):
      5     xyz[i,:] = data.GetPoint(i)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetNumberOfPoints'
```

But yeah, it doesn't seem to work anymore, and I thought with all this Numpy integration there would be something a bit neater.

EDIT2:
The output for Utkarsh's question:

```
>> clip1.UpdatePipeline()
>> rawData = servermanager.Fetch(clip1)
>> import vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter as dsa
>> # Wrap the raw data object to access NumPy friendly API
>> data = dsa.WrapDataObject(rawData) # Note I changed this from Utkarsh's "data" to "rawData"
>> print data.Points
>> print data.PointData["VelocityField"]
```

gives:

```
None
<vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter.VTKNoneArray object at 0x7f57c4a75390>
```

Comment: FYI, VTKNoneArray is returned with there's no array with that name present in the dataset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's the error you're getting with the *previous* method. It should work. Even better way is as follows:

```
# ensure that the clip1 filter is updated.
clip1.UpdatePipeline()

rawData = servermanager.Fetch(clip1)

import vtk.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter as dsa

# Wrap the raw data object to access NumPy friendly API
data = dsa.WrapDataObject(data)

print data.Points
VTKArray([[ -5.        ,  -5.        ,  -9.15493107],
   [ -3.        ,  -5.        ,  -9.75046444],
   [ -2.        ,  -5.        ,  -9.50859547],
   ..., 
   [  3.04815888,   3.        ,  10.        ],
   [  4.24629259,   3.        ,  10.        ],
   [  4.        ,   3.25505328,  10.        ]], dtype=float32)


# To access the point data array named VelocityField
print data.PointData["VelocityField"]
```

Comment: This is correct - and I think a better way to access the data.

I had problems because my initial code was not explicit enough. It was fixed by ensuring all the clips and slices had enough info to be processed correctly.